# Is having a function header that return an abstract type legal?

Tags: c++, c++11, abstract-class, language-lawyer

I was wondering of the following was legal according to the C++ standard:

```
struct Abstract { virtual ~Abstract() = 0; };

auto get_type() -> Abstract;

// I use `get_type` only to extract the return type.
using MyType = decltype(get_type());
```

GCC 6.3 accept it, but Clang 3.9 reject it.

However, if I do this instead:

```
auto get_type() -> struct Abstract;

struct Abstract { virtual ~Abstract() = 0; };

using MyType = decltype(get_type());
```

Now both compiler accept it. Are they both wrong in this case?

Comment: The `get_type()` function is never called? And `MyType` is never used outside of as a pointer or reference? I think it's okay. The compiler is discarding all that unused stuff.

Comment: Using `struct Abstract { virtual ~Abstract() = 0; }; Abstract test();` is a problem in g++ but using `struct Abstract { virtual ~Abstract() = 0; }; auto test() -> Abstract;` is not. I don't think the compiler should behave any differently for those two. I think it points to a compiler bug.

Comment: *"**[class.abstract]/3** An abstract class shall not be used as a parameter type, as a function return type, or as the type of an explicit conversion."* I believe this makes your first example ill-formed, and GCC is wrong to accept it. In the second example, `Abstract` is an incomplete type at the point it's used as a return type; it's not yet known to be an abstract class.

Comment: @AndyG Discarding such stuff isn't well defined by standard, I think that's what he's asking about, not compiler optimizations.

Comment: @KamilKoczurek: Yes, true

Comment: Whats really fun is clang will compile [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc221d4970bd1bc0) but g++ rejects it for the right reason.

Comment: Actually, the second example appears to be ill-formed, too, but for a different reason: *"**[dcl.fct]/9** Types shall not be defined in return or parameter types. The type of a parameter or the return type for a function definition shall not be an incomplete class type (possibly cv-qualified) unless the function is deleted (8.4.3) or the definition is nested within the member-specification for that class (including definitions in nested classes defined within the class)."*

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The first sentence is not violated, as the declaration does not define a type. The second sentence is not violated, as it is a return type for a function declaration which is not a function definition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In [class.abstract], pretty straightforwardly:

> **An abstract class shall not be used** as a parameter type, **as a function return type**, or as the type of an explicit conversion.

Any code that tries to do such a thing is ill-formed.

Comment: Additionally, 7.1.6.4/s [dcl.spec.auto] does not exempt the `get_type` function in this scenario because "If the function declarator includes a trailing-return-type, that specifies the declared return type of the function"

Comment: @Barry Even my second example is illegal then? So both compilers are wrong?

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Yeah, it's still using an abstract class as a function return type.

Comment: @Barry The second example is using an incomplete class as a function return type. It doesn't become an abstract class until the class's definition. I'm not convinced the second example is invalid.

Comment: Related: [CWG issue 1640](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1640), where an uninstantiated class template, which becomes an abstract class after instantiation, is used in an array declaration, causing a difference in behaviour depending on whether the instantiation has taken place already. This is seen as undesirable, and it appears to not yet be known if the standard will be changed because of it.

Comment: @hvd But after the class's definition, what we end up with is an abstract class as the function's return type. I don't see the route we take to end up there as mattering.

Comment: @Barry What does it mean to be "used" "as a function return type"? I would interpret it to mean "specified as the return type of a function type", which hasn't happened, but I can see that other interpretations (including yours) are possible too. I think this is an omission in the standard, and both accepting and rejecting the OP's second program are defensible until the standard is changed to clarify the intended behaviour.

Comment: @Barry Consider also `auto get_type() -> struct Abstract;` in one translation unit, and the definition of `struct Abstract` as an abstract class in a different translation unit. The standard cannot make that ill-formed, as ill-formed programs require a diagnostic, and it's impossible for traditional compilers (ones that compile each translation unit individually) to detect that. An interpretation that requires a diagnostic for that cannot be what's intended.

Comment: @hvd You couldn't even use such a function in the first translation unit. What would its point be?

Comment: @Barry If the return type is abstract, then there's obviously no way to actually define the function, so yeah, it'd be pretty much useless aside from testing compiler edge cases. As for whether it should be an error: in general, a type might be defined in header A, with a function returning that type being declared in header B. Header B might be included in a translation unit solely because of other declarations it contains. That could occur in a legitimate program.